# Django creates unwanted sessions when user have a session cookie

Tags: python, django, session

I have this function that check if user has an active session, I call it from other views:

```
def checkSession(request):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            a = request.session['userID']
    except KeyError:
        return False
    return True  # session is active
```

I want to avoid a creation of new session in my datebase, if user does not have one. That's why I use `transaction.atomic()`.
That's actually work in most cases. BUT, if user comes with a session cookie that does not exist in the database (for example, I deleted it from the database). Then this code will indeed return False, as expected, but still a new session key will be created for him, give him a new cookie instead of the previous one he had, and will create a row in the database - all of that I want to avoid if the user does not have a session data.
This is happening only if user come with a session cookie, and the code flows normally - i.e no internal server error in the view that call checkSession function.

why this is happening?
why there's a difference if user comes with a session cookie to the server, or doesn't come with one, if in both cases there isn't a session data for him in the database?

I user django 1.6.1

Comment: What's your primary key in the sessions table? I'm guessing from your question, that it is the cookie

Comment: I haven't modify the session table scheme at all. I use mysql as my db, the django_session table columns are: session_key(=primary key), session_data, expire_date. the client cookie value is the session_key. All normal here..